# Moisture in Vegetable Bin

Tags: storage-method

There is moisture in my vegetable bin. What can I do to prevent this? I do not have a separate control for the drawers. The refrigerator temperature is set at the manufacturer's recommended setting.

Comment: Another option is to use these storage devices which have 4 different humidity/airation settings http://smile.amazon.com/Prepworks-Progressive-International-LKS-06-Lettuce/dp/B000OUY2QO/ref=pd_sim_79_3?ie=UTF8&refRID=1YYKDAT43G49M5CCCH42&dpSrc=sims&dpST=_AC_UL160_SR160%2C160_

Answer (score 4):

Unless you are not storing produce in the vegetable drawer (aka crisper) you want moisture there. It keeps your produce from drying out. If there is excessive moisture in the crisper , make sure you are not putting in overly wet produce. You can line the drawer with paper towels to absorb excessive water and to help maintain a even humidity.

Answer (score 1):

I actually use paper bags for that purpose.  The paper towels get soggy too fast (unless you plan to keep changing them) and make me worry about mold/mildew issues.  I don't know if the paper bags work as well, that is just my solution.